# file writing at the start of a file without overwriting the text

Tags: c++, file, append, fstream, file-handling

if i have a file which stores on line 1:`this is line one`. i want to add new text before the original text of that file and then shift the original line 1 to next line without overwriting it so that it looks like

```
new text
this is line one
```

```
fstream obj("file.txt" , fstream::app)
if(obj.is_open()){
    //code
}else{
//code
}
```

now this opens the file in append mode which writes the new text i want after the original text. Is there a way to write new text before the original text of the file?

Comment: Read all lines into a `std::vector<std::string>`, insert your text at the beginning of that vector, write the whole vector back to the file.

Comment: Basically what you want is impossible on common filesystems, you have to write a new file, write your new line, then copy in the existing data

Comment: Actually writing to a new file is the best option you have in standard C++. Even using something like mapviewoffile under windows will not prevent you from having to shift the content of the file to the back (in memory). Since you insert data. Write to a new file (using a temp file name), rename the old file and rename the new one to the original filename then delete the orignal file. Added bonus if something goes wrong in your filesystem you won't have lost data)